# Hive: Remove space in string column

Tags: string, replace, hive

[image]

I have custom table and there are two space in the first_name column. I want to remove the two space to one space for this column
I try this query.

```
Select customer_id, trim(first_name)  from customer
```

But the trim does not remove the space between the characters

How can I remove two space to one space between the characters in this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `translate`

```
select customer_id,translate(first_name,'  ',' ') as first_name from customer
```

Comment: Hi VK_217, It is in the hive. I get error message"Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid function 'replace' (state=42000,code=40000)
"

Comment: Hi Vk_217, could you remove the first one and user the second one: select customer_id,translate(first_name,'  ',' ') as first_name from customer, and I will accept it as an answer. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

Use `regexp_replace` to replace consecutive multiple spaces with one space character.

```
select customer_id,regexp_replace(trim(first_name),' +',' ')
from customer
```

Comment: Hi Vamsi, your query works. Also, VK_217 translate is good. Question: regexp_replace and translate which one is faster? -Thank